# Probability chains similar to Markov chains but being functions of probability vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, reference-request, markov-chains

Does there exist a probability concept similar to Markov chains but where the matrix multiplied will be a function of the distribution vector?

For example: Two states, the vector is $p=[p_1,p_2]^T$ matrix is $P= \begin{bmatrix}p_1&p_2\\p_2&p_1\end{bmatrix}$ So the transfer matrix is altered as a function of the previous probability distribution. Instead of calculating $P^np$ as one would with Markov chain we w

1. calculates $p=Pp$
2. update $P$ according to new p
3. loop $n$ times

For first, will this even make sense in theory / be useful to some application?